# Source for finding Skype for Business Lync client application

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-2010, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I am trying to find the new Lync Skype for business client application online but couldn't able to find, if anyone know the source where can download this post the URL in the Answer section.

I found few links they are referring to Lync Skype for business Server which are useless, i require a client application for a windows 7 OS.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one you are looking for [Lync download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35451)

Comment: Thanks for your response, link you posted above is for Lync 2013 Basic  client app but i looking for Lync 2015 (Skype for business) client application.

Comment: Just install this. After that install all updates for your version of Windows. The Lync client would automatically  be upgraded to Skype For Business.

Comment: The Lync 2013 client will update itself to Skpe for Business 2015 branding through Windows Update. If your client isn't showing the new branding you may need to change the policy, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switching-between-the-Skype-for-Business-and-the-Lync-client-user-interfaces-a2394a4c-7522-484c-a047-7b3289742be0.